# Combine flags in array to single value using bitwise OR

Tags: php, arrays, function, bit-manipulation

If I have an array of flags and I want to combine them with a bitwise conjunction

ie:

```
$foo = array(flag1, flag2);
```

into

```
$bar = flag1 | flag2;
```

Does PHP have any good functions that will do this nicely for me already?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/array_reduce) will reduce an array to a single value for you:

```
$res = array_reduce($array, function($a, $b) { return $a | $b; }, 0);
```

Reduce is also sometimes called fold (fold left or fold right) in other languages.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like so

```
$bar = $foo[0] | $foo[1]
```

If the size of your array is unknown you could use [array_reduce](http://php.net/array_reduce) like this

```
// in php > 5.3
$values = array_reduce($flagArray, function($a, $b) { return $a | $b; });
// in php <= 5.2
$values = array_reduce($flagArray, create_function('$a, $b', 'return $a | $b'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$values = array_reduce($foo,function($a,$b){return is_null($a) ? $b : $a | $b;});
```

PHP < 5.3 (no closures), either of these two:

```
function _mybitor($a,$b){return is_null($a) ? $b : $a | $b;}
$values = array_reduce($foo,'_mybitor');
```

or

```
$values = array_reduce($foo,create_function('$a,$b','return is_null($a) ? $b : $a | $b;'));
```

);

Answer (score 0):

A simple suggestion to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3325695/2578286): create a sibling to `array_sum`.

```
function array_or (array $array): int {
    return array_reduce($array, function($a, $b) { return $a | $b; }, 0);
  }
```