# all array bitwise values together

Tags: php, arrays, bit-manipulation

I have an array like this.

```
$a = array(
    1,
    2,
    4,
    // ...
    64,
    // go on ...
);
```

I wanna have return

```
var_dump(1 | 2 | 4 | /* ... */ 64);
```

http://codepad.org/AseDSGh6

how can i bitwise all values in array?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325638/php-array-bitwise) but it's limit to number of values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$a = array_reduce($a, function ($v, $w){ return $v | $w; });
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't you iterate over the array? Like this example:

```
$b = 0;
foreach($a as $value) {
  $b |= $value;
}
var_dump($b);
```